# Applying new Xrandr mode do not work properly

Tags: display-resolution, xrandr

Some help please. I have successfully added new mode 1600 x 900 per the XRANDR documentation. The settings shows up in Display settings. But when I apply this, the rendering of the desktop is bad, with black bars and blurred sides. Refer the image of the error.

**Laptop Make**: DELL Insperion - 5000 AMD Ryzen series

**Screen Shot of Error**:

[image]

**Code below for the XRANDR steps followed**.

```
User@PC:~$ sudo xrandr
[sudo] password for anoop: 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 720, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.05 +  48.04  
   1680x1050     60.05  
   1280x1024     60.05  
   1440x900      60.05  
   1280x800      60.05  
   1280x720      60.05* 
   1024x768      60.05  
   800x600       60.05  
   640x480       60.05  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
User@PC:~$ cvt 1600 900
# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
User@PC:~$ xrandr --newmode "1600x900"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
User@PC:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode eDP "1600x900"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you’re missing `_60.00` from the mode line:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

Then:

```
$ sudo xrandr --addmode eDP "1600x900_60.00"
```

Be sure to add these two lines to the end of your `~/.profile` if you want the settings to persist across reboots.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The desktop still looks skewed like in the screen shot updated earlier.